# how can i add a functionality ( with the framework .net ) in shopify?

Tags: asp.net, .net, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have created eshop in shopify and I want to add functionality (with the framework .net) in shopify but I don't know how...

I searched on the internet but I didn't find anything just I found this link from the ShopifySharp github but I didn't understand how to use it.

Who can help me?

https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp

Comment: Please give more information on your setup, and what specifically is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to add functionalities to a Shopify shop depending on what you want to do.

They range from editing your shop's theme (mostly for simple needs) using html and/or js and/or and/or css and/or the [liquid templating language](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid) (be careful though that any theme update may override your edits), to developing and hosting a custom app that would interact with your shop via [a set of APIs](https://shopify.dev/api) (for more complex needs). Both techniques require a certain level of expertise (especially the later). See this very complete [blog article](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/how-to-build-a-shopify-app) for more info about how to build a Shopify app.

Basically you can build an app using any language and framework. The repo you found on Github looks like a C# SDK implementation of Shopify API. You are free to structure your app as you want provided you authenticate and communicate with Shopify using the possibilities offered by the API.